# Throw sqlexception to calling method that uses regular exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I'm trying to catch specific `SqlException` 515 (Cannot insert the value NULL into column), and I cannot precheck the value before the actual `INSERT`. I can only capture the error and determine what error it was.

In the following execution, the `alert()` can display of these msgs: that there's an empty value somewhere (from `SqlException` 515) or the generic error saying that something's wrong.

In this case, I know I can create and throw a custom exception error, but I would like to use only what I have here available since the `SqlException` will capture the exact error.

Also, those two methods are in two different classes and I only want to include `System.Data.SqlClient` where the `Insert()` method is.

Finally, I can use the regular `System.Exception` with `substring` method and search for a particular string. But there should be a better way.

So here's my pseudocode:

```
public void InsertNewCar()
{
    try
    {
        Car myCar = new Car();
        myCar.Insert();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        alert(msg); //Alerts the user: "Something missing" or "generic error"
    }
}

public void Insert()
{
    try
    {
        SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnString, CommandType.Text, sqlInsert);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 515)
        {
            //throw exception specifying that something's missing in the INSERT
        }
        else
        {
            throw ex;  //throw ex that will be interpreted as a generic error.
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: once I capture `SqlException` 515, what can I do with it? Once I throw it, I cannot check for error number within `InsertNewCar()`.

I can have `Insert()` return a value, but then the Exception will not be thrown. And I don't want to use `ref` keyword.

Thanks.

Comment: "Once I throw it, I cannot check for error number within InsertNewCar()" - you can if you catch `SqlException` in `InsertNewCar`... Or you could throw a different kind of exception and catch *that* in `InsertNewCar`.

Comment: But everything sql-related is in the class where the Insert() is. I didn't want to add `System.Data.SqlClient` namespace just for this. But I guess it can be done like that.

Comment: Right, so throw a different exception, as per the second part of my comment...

Comment: Note that your sql exception will still get caught by your InsertNewCar catch as long as it gets re-thrown from your Insert catch - SQL exception inherits from exception.  Can you be more specific as to what you mean by 'I only want to include System.Data.SqlClient where the Insert() method is"?

Comment: Yeah, throwing a different exception is the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rethrow it with a specific, other exception:

```
throw new SomethingMissingException("Some guiding text", ex /*the original exception*/);
```

In that way, you can handle it somewhere else in a more generic way. Also, don't forget to add the original exception to the exception you throw. It may come in handy some time.

Comment: I was also considering that, but I'm using `System.Exception` and `SqlClient.SqlException` so I thought that those two would be enough.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to handle the `SqlException` in `InsertNewCar` you have to do something. And working with message codes is not what you want...